# change word layout to start a newline if there are 2 words in java

Tags: java, android, regex, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm making a guess game, there is a section where you can chose letters from to fill the answer section. looks like this :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3LoA.png)

as you see it can only take one word, max 16 letters, and "space" is considered a letter too

what I want is to change the word layout so that (if) there are two words answer, it should directly create each word in a separate line, or at least create a real space between them instead of considering it as a part of the word.

this is the code of word layout in java :

```
       // draw word buttons

RelativeLayout wordLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wordlayout);
String[] word = ld.getLevelSpecific().getProcessedWord();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    Button temp = new Button(this);
    temp.setText("");
    temp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    temp.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, isd.getWordTextSize());
    temp.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    temp.setId(idCount * 2 + i); 
    temp.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
    temp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_shape_letter);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()-2),
(int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()+6*orm.getScaleRatio()));

    if (i > 0) {
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idCount * 2 + i - 1);
    } else {
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    }

    p.setMargins(isd.getExtraspaceWord()+1, isd.getExtraspaceWord(),
            isd.getExtraspaceWord()+1, isd.getExtraspaceWord());
    temp.setLayoutParams(p);
    bWord[i] = temp;
    temp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onWordPressed((Integer) v.getTag());

        }
    });
    wordLayout.addView(temp);
}
```

this is the code for the letters fields in the xml file :

```
    <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/wordlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:background="@color/background_game_light_1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_row1_left_slide"
android:persistentDrawingCache="animation|scrolling"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"  >
```